# VS Code: code is freaking out when saving

Tags: visual-studio-code

[here is a short video in google drive of the mysterious problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15w4adzUzYCHKDdtw79odAARvi6u7KttT/view?usp=sharing)

So the thing is that basically every time I try to save the project, the code freaks out and getting sorted in a weird way that I didn't want at all.

As you can see in the video, I thought maybe the Ctrl-s key is assigned to some other actions in the settings, so I tried to save the project manually via the toolbar, but it still does it.

also, it turned out that the Ctrl-s key is actually NOT assigned to any other action, so im insanely confused right now...

Comment: Here you can find all shortcut keys - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings.
Or it will be better to uninstall and then reinstall.

Comment: Searching shortcut keys and uninstalling didn't help.
Altho, i found out it's related to one of the default formats that was set to format on every save, so i changed that and it finally worked... so thanks anyway

Comment: Well, what about extensions? If you uninstall them, do you still have the problem? If so, report it directly to MS on GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and all I had to do was close VS Code and open it again.

Update:
I realized that this problem was due to the installation of an extension. I disabled all the extensions and closed the VS Code and opened it again and I saw that it was fixed and I found that extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just right now. I removed node_modules in my nextjs project and installed again. Now I can save any changes without a problem.

It is might also more secure just to change first the folder of the installed packages and install it new, otherwise can be, that you ruin your working environment and then you just have more problems than before. So just do not delete it first. :-)